# How would I made this Map key autocomplete in java?

Tags: java, typescript, dictionary

I have this Typescript code that I want to make into Java.
This is that code:

```
type CompTypes = "Texture" | "Layer" | "Sound";
let components: Map<CompTypes, Component>;
```

How would I do that in java?

Answer (score 1):

You can define an [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for `CompTypes`:

```
public enum CompTypes { Texture, Layer, Sound };
```

And create a `Component` class with the structure you want.

Then, create an [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) with `CompTypes` as `key` and `Component` as `value`:

```
EnumMap<CompTypes, Component> enumMap = new EnumMap<CompTypes, Component>(CompTypes.class);
```

You can add a new pair:

```
enumMap.put(CompTypes.Layer, new Component());
```

And get an existing one:

```
enumMap.get(CompTypes.Layer)
```

Comment: Is there anyway I could do it without an enum?